# How to chage the background color of a plot in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm wondering if i can change the `background-color` of the `plot` or at least make it transparent allowing to inherit its parent background ,
I have tried that :

**ui:**

```
plotOutput("scatterChart",
                       width = "80%",
                       height = "294px")
```

**server:**

```
  output$scatterChart <- renderPlot({
    par(bg = "yellow")
    plot(rules(), col  = rainbow(25), cex  = input$cex)
  })
```

as shown here : https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-May/033971.html

but nothing changed .

I tried that with css :

```
#scatterChart{
  background-color:red}
```

i didn't get the expected result .

or :

```
.shiny-plot-output{
  background-color:red
}
```

that change the entire div background and i even can't see the plot itself(i was exepecting that ).

Here is a picture : 
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSRsH.png)

**EDITED :**

Based on the example that *thothal* gives me , i discover that the problem was on the data passed to the plot function (it just some `association rules` obtained using `Apriori` algorithm) :

```
rules <- reactive({
    head(read.csv(input$file$datapath), input$visualization)
    transactions = read.transactions(
      file = file(input$file$datapath),
      format = "basket",
      sep = ","
    )
    minValue <- min(length(transactions),input$visualization)
    rules <-
      apriori(transactions[0:minValue],
              parameter = list(
                support = input$min_supp,
                confidence = input$min_conf
              ))
    return(rules)
  })
```

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can simply change the background color of you plot like this

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(plotOutput("p"), actionButton("go", "Go"))

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$p <- renderPlot({
      input$go
      par(bg = "navyblue")
      x <- rnorm(100)
      plot(x, 5 * x + rnorm(100, sd = .3), col = "white")
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This produces the following plot on my machine:

[image: Colored BG]

As you tried the very same, I was wondering what happens if you try to create the plot outside `shiny` does it show (with the respective `par` call) a colorful background?

Maybe some other settings in you app may override this behaviour. Can you try to run my code and see what happens?

---

If you use another plotting library (`ggplot` for instance) you have to adapt and use

```r
theme(plot.background = element_rect(...), # plotting canvas
      panel.background = element_rect(...)) # panel
```

---

**Update**

It turns out that the culprit is `arulesViz:::plot.rules`, which is grid based and ignores settings set via `par`. To get a colored background we have to add a filled `rect` to the right `viewport`.

I forked the original repo and provided a quick fix of that:

```r
devtools::install_github("thothal/arulesViz@add_bg_option_scatterplot")
data(Groceries)
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=0.001, confidence=0.8))

## with my quick fiy you can now specify a 'bg'  option to 'control'

plot(rules, control = list(bg = "steelblue")
```

[image: Colored aViz BG]

Comment: Thank for the help , Your method is perfectly working  ! i injected it in my code ,it works as well ,but when i use the same approach it doesn't work
Yeah i'm using the `arulesViz` library as well as `library(arulesViz, warn.conflicts = FALSE)` i tried to remve it but the problem still persist .

Comment: From you code snippets, I do not really see an issue. Please post a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to increase your chances to get an answer to your question.

Comment: But my guess is that, since you are implicitly using `plot.rules`, the background parameter is not respected. A quick dive into the plotting routines in `arulesViz` seems to confirm that. You have two options: you re-implement the plotting code for a `rules` object, or you ask the package maintainer to open their API to let this parameter through.

Comment: Thank you man ! should i then post that as an issue on their repo ?

Comment: Yes. I quickly forked the repository and provided a quick (hackish) fix for that. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Job is done ! Thank you so much , I really appreciate that ! I'm wondering If you can do a pull request so i can use it by just updating the existing package  (My shiny app is hosted ,i don't think it will work there ,yes ? I'm not really sure about that,that's my guess ) .

Comment: Yeah i see,it's just for the scatter plot , Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

We can use `bg` argument inside `renderPlot`:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

  # your plot

}, bg = "red")
```